# Angular Directive won't show up

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, angularjs-directive, directive

While studying about directives, I keep getting something basic wrong because I simply cannot make one work in order to import something from another html file.

HTML (`index.html`)

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html ng-app="myapp">
<head><script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.3.14/angular.min.js"></script><script type="text/javascript" src="app.js"></script></head>
<body>

 <hello-world></hello-world>

</body></html>
```

HTML (`ssth.html` - in the same directory as `index.html`):

```
<h3>hello world</h3>
```

JavaScript (app.js - same dir)

```
(function(){
var app = angular.module('myapp', []);

app.directive('helloWorld', function() {
return {
    restrict: 'AE',
    replace: 'true',
    templateUrl: "ssth.html",
};
});
})();
```

Yet my browser simply won't show the `hello word` message to me. I know there's something basic I'm missing but what?

Error reports from chrome console:

1. > XMLHttpRequest cannot load file:///.../ssth.html. Cross origin requests are only supported for protocol schemes: http, data, chrome, chrome-extension, https, chrome-extension-resource.
2. > Error: Failed to execute 'send' on 'XMLHttpRequest': Failed to load 'file:///.../ssth.html'.
3. > Error: [$compile:tpload] http://errors.angularjs.org/1.3.14/$compile/tpload?p0=ssth.html

Comment: Try to create a jsfiddle or plunker with an example :)

Comment: any error in console? you need to host you folder on server..in order to get access of template

Comment: @CookieMonster you need to host your code folder on some server like wamp or IIS

Comment: does that mean that this kind of scripting is unable to run locally..?

Comment: @CookieMonster no it is becuase you can't load template with `file://` protocol to browser..do try it from IE..it may work..

Comment: seems legit, apparently my code is ok but runs in the wrong environment/location.. thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should host you code on some server so that the template gets accessible, Because the template url which directive is going to load should have `//http` protocol.

**What happens when it uses `//file` protocol?**

While fetching that template by angular it uses `$templateRequest` to fetch the template, & `$templateRequest` API uses `$http` method to fetch the templates, and if you made any ajax call with `//file` protocol that going to fail anyhow. So by hosting your code folder on some server like WAMP, IIS, etc. will fix your issue.

**Work Around**(if you fix it without hosting code)

Other possible quick solution would be use `template` option instead of `templateUrl` like `template: "<h3>hello world</h3>"` but that would be not a better way to fix it. :)

Comment: @CookieMonster it would be good if you mark it as correct..:)

Answer (score 0):

Please check this link: http://plnkr.co/edit/e3w54TZEmfj8h5O6BX7B?p=preview,

I solved your problem in above link.

I add `<hello-world></hello-world>` in index.html and

in script.js file, i add

```
gitHubViewer.directive('helloWorld', function() {
return {
    restrict: 'AE',
    replace: 'true',
    templateUrl: "ssth.html",
};
});
```

Please review it.

Comment: your code is almost the same to mine, you have two more lines of html adding text and button. it seems to work on  plnkr.co but doesn't work locally (same console errors). i think the answer lies on @pankajparkar's comment..

Answer (score -1):

Have you added your directive script in your index.html?

```
<script src="{path}/helloWorld.js"></script>
```

Comment: just uploaded the whole thing so that you can see what the content it. im pretty sure i have missed something way too basic and my brain is turning into stew trying to figure it out..

Comment: yes, 3 errors: ____error 1: XMLHttpRequest cannot load file:///.../ssth.html. Cross origin requests are only supported for protocol schemes: http, data, chrome, chrome-extension, https, chrome-extension-resource. ___error 2: Error: Failed to execute 'send' on 'XMLHttpRequest': Failed to load 'file:///.../ssth.html'. ___error 3: Error: [$compile:tpload] http://errors.angularjs.org/1.3.14/$compile/tpload?p0=ssth.html

Comment: It can't seem to find the template file. Take a look at the answer Sanjay Parmar posted. you should be able to figure it out :)